# Swift2 setup a MTAudioProcessingTap to make a image bounce on the music beat

Tags: swift

He all, is anyone able to guide me a bit how to setup a audioprocessingtap in the keypath status, my goal is to make a image bounce on the beat of the music

```
    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    let data: AVPlayerItem = object as! AVPlayerItem

    if keyPath == "status" {
        let track = data.tracks[0].assetTrack
        let avAudioMix = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters.init(track: track)
        let callbacks = MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks(avAudioMix)
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        print("SESSION \(session)")
    }
}
```

the audio is streaming audio with avplayer

```
    func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: NSNotification){
    self.stream = notification.object! as! NSDictionary
    let stationid = notification.object!["stationid"]!
    let url = NSURL(scheme: "http", host: "adomain.com", path: "/listenstream/\(stationid!)/stream2.pls")

    if player != nil {
        do {
            PlayerItem.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata")
            PlayerItem.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges")
            PlayerItem.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp")
        }
    }
    PlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url!)
    PlayerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: [], context: nil)
    PlayerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: [], context: nil)
    PlayerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: [], context: nil)
    PlayerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: [], context: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "gotMetaData:", name: "AVPlayerItemMetadataOutput", object: PlayerItem)

    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: PlayerItem)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("StreamDataSet", object: stream)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("BufferSetter", object: "buffering...")
    bufferText = "buffering..."
    startTimer()


}
```